# HTML Coding for Specific Requirement

Tags: html

I have three words "Chapters in Book" "Journal Papers" "Conference Papers" in one line. I want my end result like "Chapters in" and Book below "Chapters in". Same way "Journal" but "Papers" below "Journal" and "Conference" and Papers below "Conference. Is it possible?

Please help me.

Comment: Just by using html? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one simple way:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Chapters in<br>Book</td>
    <td>Journal<br>Papers</td>
    <td>Conference<br>Papers</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using divs :

```
<div style="float:left; margin-right:20px">Chapters in<br/>book</div>
<div style="float:left; margin-right:20px">Journal<br/>Papers</div>
<div style="float:left;">Conference<br/>Papers</div>​
```

jsFiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/esPRr/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li>Chapters in
        <ul><li> book</li></ul>

    </li>
</ul>
​ u may go with this
```